Selection in a SwiftUI List is slow
I want to create a simple List.
Its Items shall be selectable by a single click.
On iOS (18) the items shall react on,:

doubleclick
tripleclick
longpress

On MacOS (17) the items shall react on:

doubleclick
longpress
rightclick

The clicks shall be detected in any position of the line (the text, and the spacer behind).
I have this code, which runs and fullfills the requirements, but is quite slow in selecting lines with a single click.
Any Ideas, why it´s so slow?
struct ContentView: View {
  let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"]
  @State private var selectedItem: String? = nil
  @State private var systemMessage: String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Text(selectedItem ?? "Nothing selected")
      List(items, id: \.self) { item in
        HStack {
          Text(item)
            .padding()
          Spacer()
        }
        .background(selectedItem == item ? Color.gray.opacity(0.3) : Color.clear) // show selection
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // make whole hStack Clickable
        
#if os(iOS)   // under MacOS and iOS 17 doubvleclick not detected, if .onTapGesture (count: 3) activ
        .onTapGesture (count: 3) {
          systemMessage = "triple-click: \(item)"
          selectedItem = item
        }
#endif
        .onTapGesture (count: 2) {
          systemMessage = "double-click: \(item)"
          selectedItem = item
        }
        
        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
          systemMessage = "single click: \(item)"
          selectedItem =  item
        }
        
#if os(macOS)
        
        .onLongPressGesture {
          selectedItem =  item
          systemMessage = "longpress: \(item)"
        }
#endif
        .contextMenu {
          Button("Context Menue 1") {
            systemMessage = "Context Menue 1: \(item)"
          }
          Button("Context Menue 2") {
            systemMessage = "Context Menue 2: \(item)"
          }
        }
        
      }
      Text(systemMessage)
        .font(.subheadline)
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .padding(.top, 10)
      
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
  }
}


Of course it is going to be slow. The gesture recogniser is waiting to see if you click a second time. It will trigger the single click action only if you don't click a second time. This is not possible unless the device is somehow able to read your mind/predict the future.

If you don't mind the single-click action being trigged when double-clicking, this is possible.

id: \.self isn’t a valid id
